# Documenting constants in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We all know that using magic numbers in code is a bad practice. So what's a best way to give a meaning to some constant number in query ? Usual way would be to just write a comment like so:

```
select * from
(
    select n, n % 2 rem from
    (
        select 1 n
        union all
        select 2
        union all
        select 3
        union all
        select 4
    ) tmp
) tmp2
where tmp2.rem = 0 /* Only Even Numbers */
```

But we can also do like that:

```
declare @onlyEvenNumbers int 
set @onlyEvenNumbers = 0

select * from
(
    select n, n % 2 rem from
    (
        select 1 n
        union all
        select 2
        union all
        select 3
        union all
        select 4
    ) tmp
) tmp2
where tmp2.rem = @onlyEvenNumbers
```

Or simply:

```
select * from
(
    select n, n % 2 rem from
    (
        select 1 n
        union all
        select 2
        union all
        select 3
        union all
        select 4
    ) tmp
) tmp2
where tmp2.rem = (select 0 as onlyEvenNumbers)
```

Given that sometimes queries can be very long and one line can consist of many
constant numbers - What's a best way to document these magic numbers so that usual developer could understand query faster ?

Comment: Bad example of a magic number! Naming it doesn't help the reader in any way.

Answer (score 1):

May be better?

```
select * from
(
    select n, n % 2 DivBy2Remainder from
    (
        select 1 n
        union all
        select 2
        union all
        select 3
        union all
        select 4
    ) tmp
) tmp2
where tmp2.DivBy2Remainder = 0
```

Comment: Yes, field names makes difference, except in cases where query is long and making additional nested selects (computed tables) is not very readable :-)